# Preloading images with Paperclip (in Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm not sure how to access the src of a Paperclip img. What am I doing wrong?

```
preloadImg = new Image;
preloadImg = <%= @other_images[4].image.url[:display] %>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `preloadImg.src` (and maybe wrap some quotes around the string, I don't know how Ruby handles this).

Comment: Hi pekka, I'm not sure what you mean by the rendered code... I updated the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361121/getting-url-from-paperclip-ror

Comment: Ah ha! I think I know what you mean. I am seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: original is not defined"

Comment: Alas, it was a matter of wrapping it in quotes as you said! Yikes, thank you. "<%= @other_images[4].image.url %>";